# Dimension Difference preventing plot of series

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, chart, dimensions

I have performed linear regression between the 'ro','pr' series (runoff,precipitation) and printed the chart. I want to print the linear fit on top of it and get the `R**2` value, but dimensionality prevents it. `yValues` is list of 1 element with size 98 and `xValues.map(lin)` (x values mapped in regression function) is a list of 98 elements. I tried converting both to `ee.List`, `ee.Array` but does not work. Any solution?

[image]

```
var sro = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/TERRACLIMATE') // selection based on filters
.filterDate("2017-12-30","2019-12-30")
.select("ro","aet",'pr')
.filterBounds(geometry02);

var linearFit2 = imgRegress_pre.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.linearFit(),
  geometry:small_region,
  scale: 30,
});

//------------------------------------------Regression---------------------------------------
print("---------------Pre-fire statistics-----------------------------------")
print('OLS estimates:', linearFit2);
print('y-intercept:', linearFit2.get('offset'));
print('Slope:', linearFit2.get('scale'));

var s1=sro_pre.mean(); 

// reduce region
var avPixelVals_pre = s1.reduceRegion(
    {reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), geometry: small_region, scale: 1500});

var yValues = avPixelVals_pre.toArray(['ro']);

// Get the red band value list; to be plotted along the x-axis.
var xValues = ee.List(avPixelVals_pre.get('pr'));

var lin = function(x){
  var y =ee.Number(x).multiply(linearFit3.get('scale')).add(linearFit3.get('offset'));
  return y;
};

var Yarr=ee.Array.cat([yValues,xValues.map(lin)]);


// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart8 = ui.Chart.array.values({array: Yarr, axis: 1, xLabels: xValues})
                .setSeriesNames(['Runoff','Reg'])
                .setOptions({
                  title: 'Relationship between Runoff and Precipitation',
                  colors: ['red','blue'],
                  pointSize: 4,
                  dataOpacity: 0.7,
                  hAxis: {
                    'title': 'Precipitation (mm)',
                    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
                  },
                  vAxis: {
                    'title': 'Runoff(mm)',
                    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
                  }
                });
print(chart8);
```

Comment: Your script does not run because some variables are undefined.  Can you post a link from the GetLink button, or update your script so it is complete?